How to attach several rigs to an armature without it slowing down
A model I'm working with has several accessories that can be added to the model. Each accessory has its own rig and needs to be attached to the main rig to work properly. I thought simply using a "child of" for each accessory armature would work, but this has caused the rig to be incredibly slow. Is there an alternative solution that could work for this?

since nobody reacted at all to your question, i would recommend providing a blend file to your question, which makes it much more attractive to work on. Because you didn't show us any technical settings you made, we have no idea how your model looks like and no idea how complex your rig is.

Thanks for the tip. I didn't upload a file because it's over half a GB. I do have a link to it though: https://open3dlab.com/project/8e4b16d1-8750-46b7-94a7-c7d2e054e5be/
